# Как проверить каждое сообщение в группе telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Бот должен проверять каждое сообщение, отправленное в группе. Не знаю как передать каждое сообщение в message
Вот что есть

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.entities and message.chat.id == GROUP_ID)
def echo_all(message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type in ["some_text", ]:
            bot.reply_to(message, "text")
        else:
            return
```

Comment: проверить на что?

Comment: на какой-то конкретный текст

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы не выдали Боту доступ к сообщениям

[здесь ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204633/allow-bot-to-access-telegram-group-messages)

В моем случае я обрабатываю все сообщения таким хендлером:

```
# Хэндлер на все текстовые сообщения
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
```

Comment: Доступ есть, с помощью Вашего хендлера отслеживаються только тогда когда вызываешь бота по команде. А как сделать чтобы бот отслеживал каждое сообщение?

Comment: Бот с правами админа (Has access to messages)? хм...

Comment: да, у него есть доступ к сообщениям. К примеру боту нужно проверять каждое сообщение нет ли там ссылки. И я не знаю как сделать так чтобы он сам по себе брал каждое сообщение